# I have one key name is "jeddah", how can i find in multi valued json array. My array is given below

Tags: arrays

```
"City_Wise_Fixed_Fare_EN": { "Type 1": { "jeddah": { "jeddah": "350", "riyadh": "1100" },"riyadh": { "jeddah": "1100", "riyadh": "400" }, "dammam": { "jeddah": "1400", "riyadh": "800", } },"Type 2": {"jeddah": { "jeddah": "350", "riyadh": "1200" }, "riyadh": { "jeddah": "1200", "riyadh": "500" }, "dammam": { "jeddah": "1500","riyadh": "900" } } }
```

My json like type, i have `"Type 1"` and key is `jeddah`, than how can i get `jeddah` value `350`?

Answer (score 1):

Since, `Type 1` has space between the name use the square brackets notation as

```
data.City_Wise_Fixed_Fare_EN['Type 1'].jeddah.jeddah
```

```js
var data = {"City_Wise_Fixed_Fare_EN": { "Type 1": { "jeddah": { "jeddah": "350", "riyadh": "1100" },"riyadh": { "jeddah": "1100", "riyadh": "400" }, "dammam": { "jeddah": "1400", "riyadh": "800", } },"Type 2": {"jeddah": { "jeddah": "350", "riyadh": "1200" }, "riyadh": { "jeddah": "1200", "riyadh": "500" }, "dammam": { "jeddah": "1500","riyadh": "900" } } }};
console.log(data.City_Wise_Fixed_Fare_EN['Type 1'].jeddah.jeddah);
```

Comment: @NileshBavliya glad to help you. You can tick mark the answer if it was helpful to you.